# HashSet is slower than bruteforce in Rust

Tags: rust, hashset

I'm doing some coding practice in Rust.
I found somewhat weird test result. Maybe I misunderstood something.

*Test Result*
Time elapsed in function bruteforce is: 2.387µs
Time elapsed in function hashset is: 24.413µs // Why it takes relatively long ?
Time elapsed in function rusty is: 1.13µs
test arrays::contains_common_item::test_time_measure ... ok

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

// O(N^2) O(1)
fn contains_common_item_bruteforce(arr1: Vec<char>, arr2: Vec<char>) -> bool {
    for arr1_item in arr1.iter() {
        for arr2_item in arr2.iter() {
            if arr1_item == arr2_item {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    false
}

// O(2N) O(N)
fn contains_common_item_hashset(arr1: Vec<char>, arr2: Vec<char>) -> bool {
    let mut contained_items_map = HashSet::new();

    // iter() iterates over the items by reference
    // iter_mut() iterates over the items, giving a mutable reference to each item
    // into_iter() iterates over the items, moving them into the new scope
    for item in arr1.iter() {
        contained_items_map.insert(*item);
    }

    for item in arr2.iter() {
        if contained_items_map.contains(item) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    false
}

fn contains_common_item_rusty(arr1: Vec<char>, arr2: Vec<char>) -> bool {
    arr1.iter().any(|x| arr2.contains(x)) // contains O(n)
}

#[test]
fn test_time_measure() {
    let arr1 = vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'x'];
    let arr2 = vec!['z', 'y', 'i'];
    let start = std::time::Instant::now();
    contains_common_item_bruteforce(arr1, arr2);
    let duration: std::time::Duration = start.elapsed();
    eprintln!("Time elapsed in function bruteforce is: {:?}", duration);

    let arr1 = vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'x'];
    let arr2 = vec!['z', 'y', 'i'];
    let start = std::time::Instant::now();
    contains_common_item_hashset(arr1, arr2);
    let duration: std::time::Duration = start.elapsed();
    eprintln!("Time elapsed in function hashset is: {:?}", duration);

    let arr1 = vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'x'];
    let arr2 = vec!['z', 'y', 'i'];
    let start = std::time::Instant::now();
    contains_common_item_rusty(arr1, arr2);
    let duration: std::time::Duration = start.elapsed();
    eprintln!("Time elapsed in function rusty is: {:?}", duration);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with both your testing methodology and with your expectations.

First of all: optimizations are variable, cpus are variable, caches are variable... Running a single pass, in a combined test, with fixed values is not accounting for these variables. You should be using a proper performance benchmarking test framework if you want practical results. Look into using [criterion](https://crates.io/crates/criterion).

Also, either your computer is quite slow, or you're testing in debug mode. The Rust Playground gives `210ns`, `4.25µs`, and `170ns` respectively. Benchmarking in debug mode is fairly useless since the performance wouldn't reflect how it'd behave in a release environment.

---

Second, `HashSet` purports an `O(1)` access time, but there's no such thing as a free lunch. For one thing, it is a variable sized collection that *must be built* before you can even use it. A similar crude test shows that this step alone is 4x as costly as the other two functions in their entirety. This would include allocation time, hashing time, and any other record-keeping that the `HashSet` does.

You may have been surprised by the Big-O complexity indicating that the `HashSet` should perform better, but you're probably missing that Big-O notation only shows an upper-bound of work being done and expresses how the work extends as `n` grows larger. Here, you have fixed sets of 4-5 items so the time will be more dominated by the fixed costs that Big-O notation leaves out (like the `HashSet` creation). And Big-O notation also leaves out how much work each `n` actually uses, it takes much more work to compute a hash, look-up the bucket, potentially handle collisions, and check whether an item exists; than it takes to compare two `char`s. The `n` in the `O(n^2)` of the bruteforce method and the `O(n)` of the hashset method are not directly comparable.

---

In summary, if your usage means doing intersection checks on small datasets then there's a pretty good chance that bruteforce will be faster. But you should use realistic data in a proper benchmarking test to verify.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Your comment is a nice mini-lecture for me.
You're right
I did
- test in debug mode
- put a few number of input that is not enough for Big-O
- not use proper benchmark method.
Thanks for your time and effort